# How to sort data bind to table using knockoutjs mapping plugin?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am able to bind data to a table and sort using the column headers.

However, I need to be able to edit the data so that it is updated and reflected in the corresponding table cell. To do this I need to make the data object an `observable`.

Instead of binding like this, using text binding:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: countries">
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: capital"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: population"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to bind using the `value` or `textInput` binding. Like so:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: countries">
<tr>
    <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: capital" /></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: population" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And instead of doing this:

```
        $.getJSON('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all', function(data){
            self.countries(data);
        });
```

I do this:

```
        $.getJSON('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all', function(data){
            var mappedData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            var array = mappedData();
            self.countries(array);
        });
```

If I attempt to mapped the data using the plugin, the sort does not work.

How do I mapped the data as observables and still have the capability to sort them?

Here is a working [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dvwjrw3m/): Note: I removed the mapping since it breaks the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the fiddle, the mapping plugin that you linked is wrong. The one in github is not supposed to be a cdn.

Remove the mapping plugin link you added and change it to this [link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js).

I also forked the fiddle with the correct url and added the lines that you removed.

```
var mappedData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
var array = mappedData();
```

**EDIT:**

To fix the sorting, you need to change your sorting functions to call the observable values and not the observable function. Like from:

Excerpt from `stringSort` function:

```
var countryA = a[column.property].toLowerCase(), countryB = b[column.property].toLowerCase();
```

to:

```
var countryA = a[column.property]().toLowerCase(), countryB = b[column.property]().toLowerCase();
```

You also need to modify the `numberSort`, `dateSort`, and `deepGet (which is used in objectSort)` for other sorts to work. Please check updated fiddle for the sample changes.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b04prd2g/1/) link.

Comment: Thanks my friend: I removed the above lines because the Sort does not work when the JSON data is mapped. I did not want to post code that does not work. How do I use mapped the data and still have the ability to sort?

Comment: Thank you so much my friend!